# Issues with lag() function in dplyr with grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I’m trying to apply the lag() function from the dplyr package in R to a grouped dataset. My dataset includes multiple participants, each of whom has completed multiple tasks. I want to use the lag() function to shift values from one task to the next within each participant group.

Here’s the code I’m using:

```
data <- df_effort %>%
  merge(., df_goal, by=c("participant", "block")) %>%
  merge(., df_attitude, by = c("participant")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(block)) %>%
  arrange(participant, block) %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(lag.effort = lag(slider_mentaleffort.response),
         lag.goal = lag(goal)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(a_goal = goal - lag.goal,
         a_effort = slider_mentaleffort.response - lag.effort)
```

The issue is that values seem to be “bleeding” from one participant to the next, even though I’m using group_by(participant). I’ve checked that my data is correctly sorted and that each participant is correctly identified.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

mre:

```
# Daten
mre <- data.frame(
  participant = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  task = rep(1:3, times = 2),
  variable = rep(c(10, 20, 30), times = 2)
)

# Code
library(dplyr)
result <- mre %>%
  arrange(participant, task) %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(lag.variable = lag(variable)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Try using `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::lag` instead of `mutate` and `lag` respectively.

Comment: # R version: 4.0.2
# dplyr version: 1.0.2

Comment: As Ronak implies, it's likely just a conflict with another package. Try their suggestion or restarting and only loading `dplyr`

Comment: @ronak shah: that worked. omg im crying

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::lag` instead of `mutate` and `lag` respectively. (@Ronak Shah)

It's likely just a conflict with another package. Try their suggestion or restarting and only loading `dplyr` (@jpsmith).

This worked for me!